# Proof of an invariant subspace and finding a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $U$ is a subspace of the space of infinitely differential-able (complex valued) functions of real numbers that is spanned by $f_{1}=e^{t}cos(t)$ and $f_{2}=e^{t}sin(t)$.

$A$. Prove $U$ is invariant subspace for $T(f)=\frac {df}{dt}$

$B$. Write a polynomial $p(T)$ s.t $p(T)f_{1}=0$

### My attempt

$A$. I think that to I have to show that if $U$ is the span of $f_1$ and  $f_2$ then I have to show that $T(U)\subset U$

$B$. Not sure how to approach this one. Maybe I have to find a characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Comment: $p(T)=0$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prove both $\;Tf_1,\,Tf_2\in\text{Span}\,\{f_1,f_2\}\;$ , for example:

$$Tf_1=\frac d{dt}(e^t\cos t)=e^t\cos t-e^t\sin t=1\cdot f+(-1)f_2\in\text{Span}\,\{f_1,f_2\}=U$$

For the polynomial: assuming you mean a *non-zero* polynomial (otherwise it is trivial), you can indeed take the characteristic polynomial of the restriction $\;T|_U:U\to U\;$:

$$\begin{cases}Tf_1=1f_1-1f_2\\Tf_2=1f_1+1f_2\end{cases}\implies[T|_U]=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\\!\!-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

and thus the char. polynomial of this finite dimensional operator is

$$p(x)=(x-1)^2+1=x^2-2x+2$$

CHeck now that $\;p(T|_U)f_1=0\;$ , taking into account that the vector-like form of $\;f_1\;$ in $\;U\;$ wrt the basis $\;\{f_1,f_2\}\;$ is $\;\binom10\;$

Answer (score 0):

If $ae^t\cos t+be^t \sin t \in U$, then differentiating gives $$(a+b)e^t\cos t+(a-b)e^t \sin t \in U$$